# Stemming by `hunspell` dictionary

Tags: r, text, stemming

From [Stemming Words](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corpus/vignettes/stemmer.html) I taken the following custom stemming function:

```
stem_hunspell <- function(term) {
  # look up the term in the dictionary
  stems <- hunspell::hunspell_stem(term)[[1]]

  if (length(stems) == 0) { # if there are no stems, use the original term
    stem <- term
  } else { # if there are multiple stems, use the last one
    stem <- stems[[length(stems)]]
  }

  stem
}
```

It uses the `hunspell` dictionary to do the stemming (package `corpus`).

I tried this function on the following sentences.

```
sentences<-c("We're taking proactive steps to tackle ...",                     
             "A number of measures we are taking to support ...",            
             "We caught him committing an indecent act.")
```

And then I performed the following operations:

```
library(qdap)
library(tm)

sentences <- iconv(sentences, "latin1", "ASCII", sub="")

sentences <- gsub('http\\S+\\s*', '', sentences)

sentences <- bracketX(sentences,bracket='all')
sentences <- gsub("[[:punct:]]", "",sentences)

sentences <- removeNumbers(sentences)
sentences <- tolower(sentences)

# Stemming
library(corpus)

stem_hunspell <- function(term) {
# look up the term in the dictionary
stems <- hunspell::hunspell_stem(term)[[1]]

if (length(stems) == 0) { # if there are no stems, use the original term
    stem <- term
  } else { # if there are multiple stems, use the last one
    stem <- stems[[length(stems)]]
  }
  stem
}

sentences=text_tokens(sentences, stemmer = stem_hunspell)

sentences = lapply(sentences, removeWords, stopwords('en'))
sentences = lapply(sentences, stripWhitespace)
```

I can not explain the results:

```
[[1]]
[1] ""       "taking" "active" "step"   ""       "tackle"

[[2]]
[1] ""        "numb"    ""        "measure" ""        ""        "taking"  ""       
[9] "support"

[[3]]
[1] ""           "caught"     ""           "committing" ""           "decent"    
[7] "act"
```

E.g. why commit and take appear in their ing-form? Why number became "numb"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is mostly that this is just the way `hunspell` is stemming. We can check this in an easier example:

```
hunspell::hunspell_stem("taking")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "taking"
hunspell::hunspell_stem("committing")
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "committing"
```

The  ing-form is the only option offered by hunspell. To me this doesn't make much sense either and my suggestion would be to use a different stemmer. And while we're on it, I think you would also profit from switching to `quanteda` instead of `tm`:

```
library(quanteda)
sentences <- c("We're taking proactive steps to tackle ...",                     
               "A number of measures we are taking to support ...",            
               "We caught him committing an indecent act.")

tokens(sentences, remove_numbers = TRUE) %>% 
  tokens_tolower() %>% 
  tokens_wordstem()
#> Tokens consisting of 3 documents.
#> text1 :
#> [1] "we'r"     "take"     "proactiv" "step"     "to"       "tackl"    "."       
#> [8] "."        "."       
#> 
#> text2 :
#>  [1] "a"       "number"  "of"      "measur"  "we"      "are"     "take"   
#>  [8] "to"      "support" "."       "."       "."      
#> 
#> text3 :
#> [1] "we"     "caught" "him"    "commit" "an"     "indec"  "act"    "."
```

The workflow is a lot cleaner in my opinion and the results make a bit more sense to me. `quanteda` uses the `SnowballC` package to do the stemming here, which you could integrate into your `tm` workflow if you wanted. `tokens` objects are text in the same order as the input object but tokenised (i.e., split into words).

If you still wanted to use `hunspell`, you could do so with the following function, which clears some problems you seem to have ("number" is now correct):

```
stem_hunspell <- function(toks) {

  # look up the term in the dictionary
  stems <- vapply(hunspell::hunspell_stem(types(toks)), "[", 1, FUN.VALUE = character(1))

  # if there are no stems, use the original term
  stems[nchar(stems) == 0] <- types(toks)[nchar(stems) == 0]

  tokens_replace(toks, types(toks), stems, valuetype = "fixed")

}

tokens(sentences, remove_numbers = TRUE, ) %>% 
  tokens_tolower() %>%
  stem_hunspell()
#> Tokens consisting of 3 documents.
#> text1 :
#> [1] "we're"  "taking" "active" "step"   "to"     "tackle" "."      "."     
#> [9] "."     
#> 
#> text2 :
#>  [1] "a"       "number"  "of"      "measure" "we"      "are"     "taking" 
#>  [8] "to"      "support" "."       "."       "."      
#> 
#> text3 :
#> [1] "we"         "caught"     "him"        "committing" "an"        
#> [6] "decent"     "act"        "."
```